# php compare two arrays and send to function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble to compare two arrays and return the matching values to a new function.

So I get some data from an API call to a SaaS platform which return the current stock levels from a product:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [article_number] => 010100002
            [stock] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [article_number] => 
            [stock] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [article_number] => 
            [stock] => 100
        )
etc....
```

Next I do an SQL query to grab some data from my database which need to update the current stock level, which return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [article_number] => 010100002
            [stock] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [article_number] => 010100003
            [stock] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [article_number] => 010100004
            [stock] => 0
        )

etc....
```

I want to comapre those two arrays for matching `article_number` and if there are some matching `article_number` I want to update the stock accordingly. So I want to return the matching values to a new array so I can send the new stock levels back to the API/SaaS webshop.

After some reading I thought you can test arrays like this:

```
$array1 = array($variants_sku);
$array2 = array($all_products);
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Or

```
$result = array_intersect($variants_sku, $all_products);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

But whatever I try I get an error like `Notice: Array to string conversion`. I've read what this error means but I just can't get it working!

My full code:

```
// get all variant skus and stock from webshop
    $limit = 250;

    $count = $api->variants->count();

    $variants = array();
    for($i = 0; $i * $limit < $count; $i++){
      $block_of_variants = $api->variants->get(null, ['limit' => 250, 'page' => ($i + 1)]);
      $variants = array_merge($variants, $block_of_variants);
    }

    $variants_sku = [];
    foreach($variants as $item){
      $variants_sku[] = array('article_number' => $item['sku'],'stock' => $item['stockLevel']);
    }

// get all product art. nr's and stock from database
  $all_products = array();
  $sql = "SELECT article_code, stock FROM products";
  $result = $db->query($sql);

  foreach($result as $row ) {
    $all_products[]= array('article_number' => $row['article_code'],'stock' => $row['stock']);
  }
  $db->close();

// compare SKU's and article_nr's and return an array with matching values
   $result = array_intersect($variants_sku, $all_products);
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($result);

// if there are matching article_number return an array which we can sen dback to the website
```

Comment: are `article_numbers` unique in each sub array? you might as well use them as keys (or assign the `$vartiants_sku` with `article_numbers`), then its much easier to update, plus you skip that intersect part, you can combine everything on the fetching part / block

Comment: @Kevin: Yes all article numbers are unique by themselves. Only there are matching article numbers in the webshop array and database array offcourse :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily without any functions:

```
$sass = [
            [
               "article_number" => 010100002,
               "stock" => 100 
            ],
            [
                "article_number" => null,
                "stock" => 100
            ],
            [
                "article_number" => null, 
                "stock" => 100
            ]
];


$sql = [
           [
              "article_number" => 010100002,
               "stock" => 0
           ],
           [
               "article_number" => 010100003,
               "stock" => 0
           ],
           [
               "article_number" => 010100004,
               "stock" => 0
           ]
];

$update_arr = [];
foreach($sass as $sass_prod){
    if($sass_prod["article_number"]){
        foreach($sql as $sql_prod){
            if($sql_prod["article_number"] === $sass_prod["article_number"]){
                 $update_arr[] = [
                      "article_number" => $sass_prod["article_number"],
                      "stock" => $sass_prod["stock"]
                 ];
                 break;
            }
        } 
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($update_arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming article_numbers are unique

#### Option 1 (select only matched items from database)

In this option I will select only the products with the article_numbers came from the array that you return from the SAAS API. You can loop throw the select result and build the final array (see the `$finalArray` in option 2)

```
$saasArray = [
    ["article_number" => 010100001, "stock" => 100],
    ["article_number" => 010100002, "stock" => 200],
    ["article_number" => 010100003, "stock" => 300],
    ["article_number" => 010100004, "stock" => 400]
];

$article_numbers = [];
$qMarks = "";
$types = "";
foreach($saasArray as $article){
    $qMarks .= "?, ";
    $types .= "i";
    $article_numbers[] = $article["article_number"];
}
$qMarks = rtrim($qMarks, ", ");

// $types = "iiii";
// select ..... where article_code in (?,?,?,?)
$q = "SELECT article_code, stock FROM products WHERE article_code in ($qMarks);";
$stmt = $con->prepare($q);
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$article_numbers);
$stmt->execute();
```

#### Option 2 select all items and match them with PHP

If you have an array with all the items in your DB and you want to filter it only to the article_numbers exist in the array that you got from the SAAS API, then check this option.

I will loop 2 times to build 2 indexed arrays version of the 2 arrays, then loop another time inside the DB array and remove the non matched items.

```
<?php

$saasArray = [
    ["article_number" => 010100001, "stock" => 100],
    ["article_number" => 010100002, "stock" => 200],
    ["article_number" => 010100003, "stock" => 300],
    ["article_number" => 010100004, "stock" => 400]
];

$dbArray = [
    ["article_number" => 010100001, "stock" => 0],
    ["article_number" => 010100002, "stock" => 0],
    ["article_number" => 010100003, "stock" => 0],

    ["article_number" => 010100005, "stock" => 0],
];

$saasArrayIndexed = [];
$dbArrayIndexed = [];

//bulding the indexed arrays (for better performance)
foreach($saasArray as $article){
    $saasArrayIndexed[$article["article_number"]] = $article["stock"];
}

foreach($dbArray as $article){
    $dbArrayIndexed[$article["article_number"]] = $article["stock"];
}
//remove non commen items

foreach($dbArrayIndexed as $key => $stock){
    if (!isset($saasArrayIndexed[$key])) unset($dbArrayIndexed[$key]);
}
 //now $dbArrayIndexed holds nonly the common items with the stock data from the database

 //build similar array to return to the saas api

var_dump($dbArrayIndexed);

$finalArray = [];
foreach($dbArrayIndexed as $article_number => $stock){
    $finalArray[] = ["article_number" => $article_number, "stock"=> $stock];
}

echo "final array \n";
var_dump($finalArray);
exit;
```

This will output

```
array(3) {
  [2129921]=>
  int(0)
  [2129922]=>
  int(0)
  [2129923]=>
  int(0)
}

final array
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["article_number"]=>
    int(2129921)
    ["stock"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["article_number"]=>
    int(2129922)
    ["stock"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["article_number"]=>
    int(2129923)
    ["stock"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Live demo https://3v4l.org/5kRF5

I prefer option 1 to save some resources.

Comment: if the final goal is to update said tables from db, just use the article numbers with their corresponding value from the api and directly use an update, less code and more direct

Comment: by the way you forgot the unpacking operator on the bind param of your option 1

Comment: Thanks @Kevin , I think OP needs to get the values from his DB and send the stock to the API. He doesn't want to update his DB with the values

Comment: @Kevin thanks, I will update the answer for your note

Comment: @Accountant: Kevin is right. The database stock is the actual live stock that comes from the supplier. That live stock need to be send back to the webshop. So I don't want to update my own databse. I gonna test option 2 now. Seems like exactly what I'm lloking for. The moderator has removed my text saying that this is my very first php script I'm building. So with your comments I hope I understand what does what and also understand why....

Comment: @Meules *"Kevin is right. The database stock is the actual live stock that comes from the supplier. That live stock need to be send back to the webshop. So I don't want to update my own databse"*.... That is what I told to Kevin, that you don't want to update your own database, you just want to select the stock from DB and send it to the API.